# Check if element inside a gene or not in python

Tags: python, list, integer, range, variant

I'm stuck with a python script that tries to check if some elements in a list fall within genes or outside. To do so I use the very basic following commands:

```
chr=[]
pos=[]
te=[]
chrom=[]
start=[]
end=[]
gene=[]

for line2 in infile2:
        if "#" not in line2[0]:
                line2=line2.strip()
                line2=line2.split("\t")
                chr.append(line2[0])
                pos.append(line2[1])
                te.append(line2[2])

for line in infile:
        line=line.strip()
        line=line.split("\t")
        chrom.append(line[0])
        start.append(line[1])
        end.append(line[2])
        gene.append(line[3])
for n in range(len(chrom)):
        for m in range(len(chr)):
                if chrom[n]==chr[m] and int(pos[n]) in range(int(start[m]), int(end[m])):
                        print(chr[m], pos[m], te[m], gene[n])
                else:
                        print(chr[m], pos[m], te[m], "intergenic")
```

The infile has the following structure, where the first column is the chromosome, and then we have start and end positions of the gene:

```
X   100075379   100096509   NM_001306206.2  0   +   100075405   100093350   0   15  84,79,170,137,120,138,124,63,60,142,176,293,111,126,807,    0,1136,1860,2901,3495,3729,6243,7649,10417,11124,12343,12789,16948,17848,20323
X   100075379   100096509   NM_001306209.2  0   +   100075405   100093350   0   14  84,79,170,137,120,138,73,63,142,176,293,111,126,807,    0,1136,1860,2901,3495,3729,6294,7649,11124,12343,12789,16948,17848,20323
```

The infile2 is this:

```
#CHR    POS INFO    STRAND  IDS...
X   100007156   variant -
X   10000849    variant +
X   100024284   variant -
X   10003672    variant -
X   100050489   variant +
```

The output should be the following, where NM_ is the name of the gene in RefSeq format:

```
X 100628757 variant NM_000061.3
X 101152133 variant NM_001011657.4
X 100602245 variant intergenic
X 100236510 variant intergenic
X 100244318 variant NM_001162491.2
```

The problem is that the output returns only "intergenic" variants, while I know that at least 30-40% of elements in my list are within genes.
Can someone help me?

Comment: would it be possible to edit the question so that we could see some example data from `infile` and `infile2` as well as what you expected the results to be?

Comment: Your test data does not seem to match your intended output.

Comment: `chr` is a python built-in, consider renaming it to avoid troubles

Answer (score 0):

If I add a row to `infile2` that I believe should trigger a match

```
    X   100075380   variant +
```

This this code (note the +1 on the end to make the range inclusive) seems to work:

```
## -----------------------
## build a version of infile
## -----------------------
with open("infile.txt", "r") as file_in:
    infile = [
        [cell.strip() for cell in line.strip().split("\t")[:4]]
        for line in file_in
        if line.strip()
    ]
print("\ninfile:")
for row in infile:
    print(row)
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## build a version of infile2
## -----------------------
with open("infile2.txt", "r") as file_in:
    infile2 = [
        [cell.strip() for cell in line.strip().split("\t")[:3]]
        for line in file_in
        if line.strip()
    ][1:]
print("\ninfile2:")
for row in infile2:
    print(row)
## -----------------------

print("\nResults:")
for infile_row in infile:
    chrom = infile_row[0]
    start = int(infile_row[1])
    end = int(infile_row[2])
    gene = infile_row[3]

    for infile2_row in infile2:
        chrom2 = infile2_row[0]
        pos = int(infile2_row[1])
        te = infile2_row[2]

        if chrom == chrom2 and pos in range(start, end + 1): # should the range be inclusive?
            print(chrom, pos, te, gene)
        else:
            print(chrom, pos, te, "intergenic")
```

That gives me:

```
infile:
['X', '100075379', '100096509', 'NM_001306206.2']
['X', '100075379', '100096509', 'NM_001306209.2']

infile2:
['X', '100007156', 'variant']
['X', '10000849', 'variant']
['X', '100024284', 'variant']
['X', '10003672', 'variant']
['X', '100050489', 'variant']
['X', '100075380', 'variant']

Results:
X 100007156 variant intergenic
X 10000849 variant intergenic
X 100024284 variant intergenic
X 10003672 variant intergenic
X 100050489 variant intergenic
X 100075380 variant NM_001306206.2
X 100007156 variant intergenic
X 10000849 variant intergenic
X 100024284 variant intergenic
X 10003672 variant intergenic
X 100050489 variant intergenic
X 100075380 variant NM_001306209.2
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it gives me an error ("for line in infile.split("\n") AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'"). Is it because I wrote in the script, before your code, 'infile=open("filename.bed")'?

Comment: I updated to read the data from a pair of files